# How to call IIS hosted WCF Service from SharePoint 2013 workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, web-services, wcf, web

I have a WCF service deployed in IIS Website. I am able to invoke the service from web browser using service url -

```
  http://localhost/Service.svc/get/hello
```

It returns data in XML format as desired -

```
  <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">hello</string>
```

What I need is to use the service in SharePoint workflow using the 'Call HTTP Web Service' action. I am specifying the url which is same as earlier, with GET method and no body -

```
  http://localhost/Service.svc/get/hello
```

The action looks like below 

[image]

But when I execute the workflow, the service is not called. Instead the workflow fails to start with a message like - 

[image]

What could be a possible solution?

Comment: what did you write into the request/response parameter?

Comment: The request and response parameters are empty

Comment: more, I also tried to call the service using jQuery AJAX. There is some problem too. As I see on the console the console says 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource'. Still not sure if the SharePoint workflow is facing the same issue.